# Keyboard input on OSX

Tags: c, macos, input, keyboard, keylogger

I was wondering if it was possible to read the keyboards input, on OSx from somewhere, such as GNU/Linux with the /dev/input files.

The purpose of this is to make a very simple keylogger, (learning purpose), or if there is a function that i could call in C.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since not all readers have good intentions as you, I won't get into details, but rather point you to the right direction.

As you may know, the WindowServer works over two environments: Carbon (old) and Cocoa (new). These are the respective APIs:

1. Carbon → <del>[InstallEventHandler](http://oreilly.com/catalog/learncarbon/chapter/ch06.html)</del> (link is broken due to age? Anyway, the referenced book is [Learning Carbon](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001612.do), Chapter 6 - Carbon Events)
2. Cocoa → [addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:)